# R - How to convert this nested for loop into an lapply function that can mutate a list

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I have data that looks like this

```
aList <- list(a1 = c("apple", "banana", "orange", "strawberry", "cherry"),
              a2 = c("banana", "cherry", "apple"),
              a3 = c("apple", "strawberry", "pineapple"),
              a4 = c("raspberry", "strawberry", "apple"),
              a5 = c("pineapple", "lemon", "orange", "banana", "apple"),
              a6 = c("lemon", "apple", "blueberry"),
              a7 = c("watermelon", "apple", "banana", "mango"),
              a8 = c("mango", "cherry", "apple", "lemon"),
              a9 = c("orange", "banana", "strawberry"),
              a10 = c("mango", "strawberry"))
```

I'd like to get it into a vertical format, like what happens when you run this code:

```
vertical_data <- list()
for (x in names(aList)) {
  for (y in aList[[x]]) {
    if (is.null(vertical_data[[y]])) {
      vertical_data[[y]] <- x
    } else {
      vertical_data[[y]] <- c(x, vertical_data[[y]])
    }
  }
}
vertical_data
```

I'd like each entry to tell me where the particular fruit occurs.

This was easy enough to do with a double for loop. But when I do the same thing with a nested lapply function, it looks like it doesn't modify the list (i.e. vertical_data) at all. Why is that? The reason I'd like to do this with an apply function is because it's faster. My actual dataset will have thousands of items, and "fruits". It'll take way too long with for loops.

I'd really appreciate the help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `split` on the `unlist`ed data

```
split(rep(names(aList), lengths(aList)), unlist(aList))
```

---

Or another option would be to `stack` to a two column 'data.frame' and then do the `split`

```
with(stack(aList), split(as.character(ind), values))
#$apple
#[1] "a1" "a2" "a3" "a4" "a5" "a6" "a7" "a8"

#$banana
#[1] "a1" "a2" "a5" "a7" "a9"

#$blueberry
#[1] "a6"

#$cherry
#[1] "a1" "a2" "a8"

#$lemon
#[1] "a5" "a6" "a8"

#$mango
#[1] "a7"  "a8"  "a10"

#$orange
#[1] "a1" "a5" "a9"

#$pineapple
#[1] "a3" "a5"

#$raspberry
#[1] "a4"

#$strawberry
#[1] "a1"  "a3"  "a4"  "a9"  "a10"

#$watermelon
#[1] "a7"
```

---

Or as @rawr mentioned

```
unstack(stack(aList)[2:1])
```

---

Regarding the assignment within the `lapply` and the `for` loop, it is based on the environment.  In the `for` loop, the assignment modifies the object in the global env, but in `lapply`, it is a self-contained env or else have to do `<<-` (not advisable) or specify the env as the global env

```
vertical_data <- list()
lapply(names(aList), function(x) lapply(aList[[x]], 
      function(y) if (is.null(vertical_data[[y]])) {
         vertical_data[[y]] <<- x
         } else {vertical_data[[y]] <<- c(x, vertical_data[[y]])
         }))
```

Comment: or `unstack(stack(aList)[2:1])`

Comment: Thank you! Why is it that <<- isn't advisable? And is specifying the global env better, or is it also not advised?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `enframe` to convert names list to dataframe and then split `name` based on `value`.

```
tibble::enframe(aList) %>% tidyr::unnest(value) %>% {split(.$name, .$value)}

#$apple
#[1] "a1" "a2" "a3" "a4" "a5" "a6" "a7" "a8"

#$banana
#[1] "a1" "a2" "a5" "a7" "a9"

#$blueberry
#[1] "a6"

#$cherry
#[1] "a1" "a2" "a8"

#$lemon
#[1] "a5" "a6" "a8"

#$mango
#[1] "a7"  "a8"  "a10"

#$orange
#[1] "a1" "a5" "a9"

#$pineapple
#[1] "a3" "a5"

#$raspberry
#[1] "a4"

#$strawberry
#[1] "a1"  "a3"  "a4"  "a9"  "a10"

#$watermelon
#[1] "a7"
```